# C++ pointer arithmetic loop access violation

Tags: c++, memory-management, function-pointers

I'm trying to work with a contiguous block of memory in C++, of floats. The memory represents pixel data for a proprietary image library I'm working with. I can't change the fact that the library takes a pointer to the first float for it's creation routine. For example, a 20x20 image would be held in memory as 400 contiguous floats.

As below, I'm using a loop to test population of this memory.

I'm incrementing the pointer with each loop iteration, however I'm getting an access violation at runtime - obviously I'm over-running the heap somehow. I fear I'm not incrementing the pointer correctly, or misunderstanding this.

Where am I going wrong? I would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes ran over this :) thanks

```
int width = 500;
int height = 500;
float *img = (float*) calloc(width * height, sizeof(float));

int count = 0;
while (count < (width * height))
{
    *img = 1.0f;
    count++;
    img++;
}

saveImage(width, height, img, TEXT("test.tiff"));

free(img);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me - are you checking the return value from calloc to ensure the memory could be allocated (though I'd be surprised if it couldn't)?

Comment: @Derek: Not fine.  `img` points one past the end of the memory block when it is passed to `saveImage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm incrementing the pointer with each loop iteration,

And that's the problem; `img` no longer points to the beginning of the image as `saveImage` likely expects.  I'm sure that `saveImage` will be traversing across `img` to `img + (width * height - 1)`, so it is running past the boundaries of the memory you allocated.

Use a temporary pointer or indexing:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < (width * height))
{
    img[count] = 1.0f;
}

saveImage(width, height, img, TEXT("test.tiff"));
free(img); // and now this is correct as well
```

Comment: Thanks - I had this thought just before writing the question. In fact, I implemented a second solution using a const float pointer as a temporary one instead. It makes complete sense - thank you. As an side, I didn't know you could subscript index memory like you've demonstrated there

Comment: @WhozCraig, where was the memory leak?

Comment: @George: You were passing a modified pointer to `free`.  Undefined behavior.   You must pass the same pointer to `free` that you received from `malloc`, `calloc`, etc.  This means the same pointer *value*, not the variable itself (i.e., a copy of the original would be fine, but not anything which does not contain the same initial *value*).

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. I suppose this solution is also more efficient and elegant than a "temporary pointer" solution?

Comment: @George Yes there was a leak. It helps a LOT to remember that pointers are nothing more than variables that *hold* addresses. As you incremented your pointer, you "abandon" the address it was originally assigned (from calloc()), and eventually passed an invalid address to `free()` and `saveImage()`. What you wrote will work fine if you saved off the original allocation to a separate pointer variable, then used that for both your `saveImage()` and `free()` call, but Ed's code is *much* clearer to understand what your code is doing, and I advise you use it.

Comment: @George: Nope, they're going to be identical in any way that matters.  Also note that indexing `img[index]` is the same exact thing as offsetting `*(img + index)`.  This is why `img[index]` is the same as `index[img]`.  You can actually write things like `10[img]` because addition is associative.

Answer (score 4):

You are altering img in the loop. When you call saveImage the img pointer is <strike>at the end</strike> after the end of the image, not at the beginning!

Comment: Technically speaking, it's *past* the end of the image.

Comment: @NikBougalis Technically speaking, where the end iterator points? :-)